# Symfony2 doesn't display validation errors in production

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to show serverside validation errors to the user if they appear, but instead it shows:

```
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
```

In dev. environment though it does render my view with errors. Here's the code:

```
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    return $this->render('ExampleTestBundle:Error:error.html.twig',
        array(
            'errors' => $errors,
            'route' => 'example_route'
            )
        );
    }
```

How can I show the `error.html.twig` view in production with errors in it?

Comment: Are you sure it is the validation errors that are causing the `500`? What are your logs saying?

Comment: I am almost entirely sure as I am deliberately causing "unique username" error and it renders the view in dev environment with the correct messages. It should be showing it in production as well, right?

Comment: Not always. Some things don't get caught in dev that would otherwise stop a page working in production. I've had issues like this where I thought the same but found I had missed something that showed up in my logs (in both dev and prod) but I had never needed to look in dev so had never seen the error.

Comment: Right...I just checked my production logs and it shows: "SoapFault: username_error_unique<br>\r\nDuplicate username"...I get it now, Symfony validates objects and db, but that exception comes from ISPConfig where I am creating a user. But how can I customize an exception thrown by ISPConfig?

Comment: A comment in the php site says... To get custom Soap Error Codes use in the catch $e->faultcode instead of $e->getCode. 

<?php 
try { 
    // ... 
} catch (SoapFault $e) { 
    echo $e->faultcode; 
}

Comment: Thanks pal, I tried all the steps you suggested and they led me to reason the problem was caused by the fact that I needed to clear my cache after having made changes in my code before trying in production. I'm gonne post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the fact that you have to clear your cache each time you make a change to the code before trying it in production:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

After I cleared the cache, it started validating in the production envivonment as well.

Comment: remember: clearing your cache is the Symfony equivalent of "have you tried switching it off and on again?" ;)